# Calculate distance between two lat+lng coordinates in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've got an object containing the lat and lng of my companys facilities. I've also got an object containing the lat and lng of the user's current location. What I'd like to do is iterate through the object with the location data of the sites, and calculate the closest one to the user's location. I'd like to get the kilometers between the two as well as the time it would take to drive the distance.

I've been looking at [Google's Geometry API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) but can not figure out how to use this in React Native, if it's possible.

My question is what I should do to best achieve this? Can I somehow use the Google Geometry API?

**Edit:** I don't have to do this in the app, preferably I'd like to do so, but if it's not possible I could simply make a fetch to my PHP API if there is a better solution for PHP.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The npm package geolib https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib has several methods that can help you do this; getDistance, findNearest, and orderByDistance.

Comment: This looks very promising! Thanks for your reply. I will take a look at this first thing in the morning and get back to you!

Comment: After testing this, it's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to get the driving distance between two points ??

Comment: You'd need something that could route based on roads.  Google might have an API for their map directions feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
calculateDistance(lattitude1, longittude1,lattitude2,longittude2)
{
    
const toRadian = n => (n * Math.PI) / 180

    let lat2 = lattitude2
    let lon2 = longittude2
    let lat1 = lattitude1
    let lon1 = longittude1

    console.log(lat1, lon1+"==="+lat2, lon2)
    let R = 6371  // km
    let x1 = lat2 - lat1
    let dLat = toRadian(x1)
    let x2 = lon2 - lon1
    let dLon = toRadian(x2)
    let a =
      Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
      Math.cos(toRadian(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRadian(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
    let c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a))
    let d = R * c
    console.log("distance==?",d)
    return d 
      }
```

**calculateDistance(25.3773009 68.3034496,25.3947972 68.3312881);**

Comment: Please provide a description not only solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this updated working code!

```
import {getDistance} from 'geolib';
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

export default class Locations extends Component
{
    state = {  
        destinationLat: 31.6200,
        destinationLong: 74.8765,
        distance:null,
        startLat:52.528308,
        startLong:1.3817765
    };
    async componentDidMount(){
        let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
        });
        this.setState({
            startLat: location.coords.latitude,
            startLong: location.coords.longitude,
          });
        var dis = getDistance(
            {latitude: location.coords.latitude, longitude: location.coords.longitude},
            {latitude: this.state.destinationLat, longitude: this.state.destinationLong},
          );
          this.setState({
            distance: dis/1000,
          });
    };
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>{this.state.distance} KMs</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This is an example of calculating the distance between two points, using ts

This is not 100% accurate, if you need a more accurate calculation please go and check [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html)

If you need more calculation then you can use [this lib](https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib)

> Note: I created these methods based on the lib and while searching, I
> did not want to install the complete library because all I need is
> distance calculation.

```
type UseDistanceTypes = {
  from: { latitude: number; longitude: number };
  to: { latitude: number; longitude: number };
};

const earthRadius = 6378137;
const toRadius = (value: number): number => (value * Math.PI) / 180;

export const useDistance = ({ from, to }: UseDistanceTypes): number => {
  const distance =
    Math.acos(
      Math.sin(toRadius(to.latitude)) * Math.sin(toRadius(from.latitude)) +
        Math.cos(toRadius(to.latitude)) * Math.cos(toRadius(from.latitude)) * Math.cos(toRadius(from.longitude) - toRadius(to.longitude)),
    ) * earthRadius;

  return Math.round(convertDistance(distance, 'km'));
};

// Convert to a different unit

const convertDistance = (meters: number, targetUnit: keyof typeof distanceConversion = 'm'): number => {
   return distanceConversion[targetUnit] * meters;
};

const distanceConversion = {
  m: 1,
  mi: 1 / 1609.344,
  km: 0.001,
  cm: 100,
  mm: 1000
};
```

> You can put it inside a memo, but I do not see any benefits in my case because the lat and long props will always change.
> I am using here just javascript (typescript) so it can be used in react too, btw i am using this method in my React native app.